# Multi Language Support in iphone application

Tags: iphone, multilingual

I want to develop an iphone application where u can change the language from the application itself rather than iphone settings.

How can it be possible??
Is there any tutorial available for it??

Waiting for the responses.

Regards,
Jagruti

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial
for creating String file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+(void)GetLangKey:(NSString *)Langkey
{
    NSString *tmpstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"LanguageResources" ofType:@"bundle"]]; 
    tmpstr =[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    tmpstr=[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:Langkey];
    tmpstr =[tmpstr stringByAppendingString:@".lproj"];

    //  NSLog(@"%@",tmpstr);
    myLocalizedBundle=[NSBundle bundleWithPath:tmpstr];
}

+(UIImage*)GetLocalImage:(NSString *)ImgName
{
    NSString *filepath= [myLocalizedBundle pathForResource:ImgName ofType:@"png"]; 
    UIImage *returnImg=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    return returnImg;
}

+(UIImage*)GetLocalImage:(NSString *)ImgName Type:(NSString *)imgType
{
    NSString *filepath= [myLocalizedBundle pathForResource:ImgName ofType:imgType]; 
    UIImage *returnImg=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    return returnImg;   
}

+(NSString *)getLocalvalue:(NSString*)Key
{
    NSString *localValue=NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(Key,@"Localized",myLocalizedBundle,@"");
    //NSLog(@"%@",localValue);
    return localValue;
}

when you changed Language change kay
[YourAppDelegate GetLangKey:(btn_Language.selected)?@"sp":@"en"];
```

Create Two Bundles As Strings Files Names Sp.lproj AND en.lproj 
   Give Same Key For Both Strings 
   Get Value Like Below
    [YourAppDelegate getLocalvalue:@"Settings"];